# Помогите, готовлюсь к Олимпиаде

Tags: java

Олимпиада ориентирована на Паскаль, но я его плохо знаю, зато знаю Java. Одно из  условий на олимпиаде это работа с файлами, то есть в текстовый документ (input) вводятся значения переменных и при запуске программы ответ появляется в другом текстовом файле (output). Учитель показал как это делается в Паскале, было понятно и в принципе легко. Придя домой решил найти как сделать так же в Java, но не смог  разобраться. Вся надежда на вас, объясните пожалуйста как осуществить работу с файлами в Java на примере задачи - сложить число A и B.
Буду очень благодарен

Comment: https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/7018?locale=ru

Comment: Спасибо! попытаюсь разобраться

Answer (score 0):

Метод для получения строк из файла:

```
static String[] getLines(String filesName){
    ArrayList<String> splitted = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(filesName));
        while(sc.hasNext()){
            splitted.add(sc.nextLine());
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {System.err.println("Не могу найти файл");}

    return splitted.toArray(new String[splitted.size()]);
}
```

Метод для записи строк в файл:

```
static boolean writeTheseLinesInsteadOldLines(String filesName,String[] strs) {
    try(BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filesName, false)))
    {
        for(String s:strs) {
            writer.write(s);
            writer.newLine();
        }
        writer.close();
        return true;
    }
    catch(IOException ex){System.err.println("Указанного файла не существует");} 

    return false;
}
```